# Converting two column csv file data into a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I have a .tsv file with two columns of data. I want to create a dictionary where for each row, data of column 1 will be the key and data of column 2 will be the value of a dictionary. I am new to python and having trouble figuring it out.

I have tried using pandas but I am not being able to do it. It would be helpful if I can get a solution without pandas.

I am unable to separate the two columns of data and they are coming together.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Can you show a minimal example of the input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the entire setup of your problem, I can only provide a general idea to point you in the right direction, but here goes.

To load a CSV file, your best bet is Numpy's `genfromtxt` function, the documentation for which is at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html .

Let's say your data is stored in some file `data.csv`.  We can extract your data with the following couple of lines.

```
import numpy as np
labels, values = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

This gives us two arrays, one holding label information and the other holding value information.  I can do this by setting `unpack=True`, which separates the data in the CSV file into columns.  Also, because this is a CSV file, I choose a comma to be my delimiter between entries.

Now let's create a dictionary with those arrays.  This can be achieved with a simple `for` loop.  We can iterate over `labels` and `values` in tandem using Python's `zip` function, which lets us do the following:

```
data_dict = {}
for label, value in zip(labels, values):
    data_dict[label] = value
```

This results in a dictionary that holds a set of values linked to a set of labels, both of which you extracted from a CSV file.